# Creating new object returns field with None value

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a new object of my model, but keep on getting a value of none for one field.

My models look like this:

```
class KeyCategory(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey('Program', verbose_name='Programm', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('Event', through='EventQuota')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together = ("program", "name")
        permissions = (
            ('view_key_category', 'Have access to categories'),
        )


class EventQuota(models.Model):
    key_category = models.ForeignKey(KeyCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='key_quota')
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='key_quota')
    quota = models.PositiveIntegerField('Quota', default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Quota'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quotas'
        unique_together = ('key_category', 'event')
```

When I try now to create a KeyCategory and my EventQuota, the field "events" for KeyCategory always returns `core.Event.None`

```
        if program.pk == 1:
            for _ in range(0, 2):
                key_category = KeyCategory(
                    program=program,
                    name=random.choice(self.eventList)
                )
                key_category.save()
                event_quota = EventQuota(
                    key_category=key_category,
                    event = random.choice(eventList),
                    quota = random.randint(0,100)
                )
                event_quota.save()
```

Note: the `eventList` in the `random.choice` is a queryset list of objects.

I tried to follow Djangos [Extra fields on Many-to-Many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) example, but somehow it seems that I'm missing something here or doing something not the right way? Would appreciate any help! Thanks in regard.

Logging:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug(key_category.events)
```

Comment: First off, names that you use in models are not the same used in views, please correct. It's confusing. Why using the prefix `access` in model name, field name

Comment: @Lemayzeur sorry my mistake, I changed some names before and copied a wrong snippet, now its correct

Comment: How/Where do you know that `events` returns en empty value?

Comment: @Lemayzeur I logged/debugged the field after the for loop and checked its value and thus saw that it returned `core.Event.None`

Comment: I am not sure the it's `None` at all since `core.Event.None` just return a concatenation of the app name + the model name + string representing the instance in case you had defined an `__str__()` method in Event model. To make sure, check your Event model directly

Comment: what are you getting for `key_category.events.all()`?

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you are logging this data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question with how I log my stuff

Comment: @ruddra this actually returns a valid queryset with an event inside it! But why is just `key_category.events` returning `None` while .all() returns a queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access key_category.events you are asking for the value of a field (or a single object for foreign key fields). However with a ManyToMany relationship you are asking for multiple objects (a queryset).
Using key_category.events.all() returns the objects related to the key_category, not just a single value.

```
core.events.all()
```